# How to create AppIndicator with Python?

Tags: application-development, python, indicator

I have no knowledge of Python, but because ubuntu recommends it i will use it for the appinidcator.. So i got these 2 files:

[image]

and the code of the .py file is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import appindicator
import pynotify
import gtk

a = appindicator.Indicator('wallch_indicator', '/home/paul/scripts/wallch_tray.png', appindicator.CATEGORY_APPLICATION_STATUS)
a.set_status( appindicator.STATUS_ACTIVE )
m = gtk.Menu()
ci = gtk.MenuItem( 'Check' )
qi = gtk.MenuItem( 'Quit' )

m.append(ci)
m.append(qi)

a.set_menu(m)
ci.show()
qi.show()

def checkStatus(item):
        import urllib2
        htmltext = urllib2.urlopen('http://youtube.com/wichitsombat').readlines()
        neededline = []
        for line in htmltext:
                if line.strip().find('stat-value') > -1:
                        neededline.append(line) 

        n = neededline[0]
        subs = n[n.find('>')+1:n.rfind('<')]
        n = neededline[1]
        views = n[n.find('>')+1:n.rfind('<')]

        # show the notification message
        pynotify.init('wallch_indicator')
        n = pynotify.Notification('<b>Paulgramming Channel</b>',
                'subscribers: %s   views: %s'%(subs, views),
                'notification-message-im')
        n.show()

ci.connect('activate', checkStatus)

def quit(item):
        gtk.main_quit()

qi.connect('activate', quit)

gtk.main()
```

Code taken from this video [How to make notification program using Python](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8cdrJA3PbEw)

When i run `python wallch_indicator.py` it keeps running but i don't see the indicator..What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Works perfectly fine here. I have no clue as to why it shouldn't work on your machine. You don't get any error output when running it?

Comment: No error.. I must CRTL+C, and then i get "^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "wallch_indicator.py", line 47, in <module>
    gtk.main()
KeyboardInterrupt"      Do i miss a dependency or something? ..

Comment: check the path to the icon /home/paul/scripts/wallch_tray.png

Comment: If you would be missing a dependency you should face an exception like `ImportError` for Python.

Comment: You are right wojox, i forgot to change that one, all works now, thanks ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check the path to the icon `/home/paul/scripts/wallch_tray.png`